# mysql vb.net - Storing a mysql table in a bindinglist

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How do you make a bindinglist that stores a mysql table of products which is then returns datas from that table into a listbox?

Here's the video I'm trying to mimic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99LWDWmSAqM&list=PL70BEFACCE6BFAF6F&index=8

but it's all in c# and uses a different type of database.

Comment: If the data is in a DataTable, you dont need to move it to a BindingList - just use the DataTable

Answer (score 0):

you can do it through multiple ways

1. The dirty way: Use code converter C# to vb
   http://converter.telerik.com/
2. use widget to make mysql connection and bind list to a listbox 
   [image]
3. Manually code and add data to listbox

Comment: my problem really is getting the mysql table

it'll go something like
Private bindlist As New BindingList(Of mysqltable)